# How to implement auto renewal subscription for in app purchase?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

I am completely new to In App Purchases and need to implement a subscription based IAP to grant user access to my app on login.

My app contains two types of users:

- Regular user
- Business user

In my business user table, I plan to have a column for **subscriptionPaid** which holds a boolean value and another column for the **expDate**.

At a high level, my plan is to update these two columns every time a user renews their subscription. Then, when a business user **logs in**, in addition to checking username and password, I need to check if the **subscriptionPaid bool is true**.

1. I had a quick look but I'm wondering if there are **events** which are triggered when renewals occur whereby I can call my own webservice to update the **subscriptionPaid** col and the **expDate** col in my business user table? Is this the best way of implementing such a process?
2. I know in Android, there is a method **getPurchases** which a programmer could potentially call on login to my app and then if there is an active one for my app, I will call my update script there to update the **subscriptionPaid** and **expDate** fields in my DB. I will be coding in swift, so would need some swift equivalent of the android getPurchases if this option is a better choice?
3. And finally, Apple can be very strict at times so I am wondering if anyone has any experience or opinion on whether or not what I have described thus far, would fit the following criteria:

   Auto-renewable subscriptions. Episodic content. Like non-consumable products, auto-renewable subscriptions remain available to the user indefinitely on all of the user’s devices. Unlike non-consumable products, auto-renewable subscriptions have an expiration date. You deliver new content regularly, and users get access to content published during the time period their subscription is active. When an
   auto-renewable subscription is about to expire, the system automatically renews it on the user’s behalf.

This is the type of product I need. See all options below:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html

Comment: As a side remark, having 2 fields is probably unnecessary and calls for further desynch. Just keep the expiration date field and your "boolean" flag is then just a matter of knowing if expiration date is in the past.

Comment: @LaurentS thanks for the tip